# SwiftUI - Trying to re run a class from a different view to force data to reload

Tags: swiftui

I'm new to SwiftUI and struggle sometimes with the whole 'declarative' concept but normally get there in the end...Anyway I've made a simple app that loads data from a remote JSON file on line. That part all works fine.
What I then want to do is, on a different view, I call the class FetchData - trying to get it to revisit the data source and update the variables. It appears It runs the class ok, as the print statements reappear when called - but the variables do not update with new values.

Heres code for the class to load the data.

```
    import SwiftUI


struct GetData: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var CODE: String
    var RATE: Double
    var TIME: String
    var FLAG: String
    var COUNTRY: String
    var NAME: String
    
   
}



public class FetchData: ObservableObject {
 
  
  // 1.
   @Published var rates = [Rates]()
    @State var showingAlert = true
    
    init() {

        let url = URL(string: "https://www.exampledata.co.uk/example.php")!
        // 2.
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [self](data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let processData = data {
                    // 3.
                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Rates].self, from: processData)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       
                        self.rates = decodedData
                        print("Data Loaded from Internet")
                        self._showingAlert = State(initialValue: false)
                        
                    }
                } else {
                    print("No data")
                    self.rates=exchange
                    // use diferent method to load data from hardcopy if no internet avail
                    print("Data Loaded from Hardcopy")
                    self._showingAlert = State(initialValue: true)
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error")
                self.rates=exchange
                print("Data Loaded from Hardcopy")
                // use diferent method to load data from hardcopy if server down or general error
                self._showingAlert = State(initialValue: false)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Then in the other view where I want to call it from I have ...

```
        Text("Data last updated:" + RowData.TIME)
            .font(.footnote)
            .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                Button(action: {
                    FetchData.init()

                }) {
                    HStack{
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.clockwise").resizable()
                        .frame(width: 15.0, height: 15.0)
                        Text("Reload rates")
                            .font(.footnote)
                    }}
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

2 things

First, [`@State`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state) should only be used in a `View` not an `ObservableObject` per the documentation. Switch `@State` to `@Published`.

Second, and what is probably your issue is in your `view`. How are you [initializing the `ObservableObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app)(Code not available)? it should be an `@ObservedObject`, [`@EnvironmentObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentobject), or [`@StateObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/stateobject). Also, make sure you aren't creating two different instances a [singleton pattern](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/managing_a_shared_resource_using_a_singleton) or an [`@EnvironemntObject`](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input) can help with that.